# How to hide a document in the Site Assets Sharepoint 2010

Tags: hide-elements

In my Site Assets page I have a list of documents.

```
https://.../SiteAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

I wish the keep everything there visible except for one item. I do not want to delete it, I just want to hide it with the ability to unhide it in the future.

How do I hide just one item in the site assets?

Please note I need to do this in the web interface, not in Designer.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not break the permissions on the item and take away read access?

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution is to update the default view of the Site Assets library and filter out the item that you do not want to see.

Steps:

- Modify the *All Documents* view.
- Scroll down to the *Filter* section on the *Edit View* webpage.
- Add the following filter:

  - **Name**
  - is not equal to
  - *add_the_name_of_the_file_here*
- Click *OK* to save the view with the filter.

Voila.

---

Another solution is to remove all permissions from the item, although site collection administrators will still see it.

Comment: How do I get to "All Documents view"?

Comment: The Site Asests library should have a default view called "All Documents". Every time you open the library, you look at that library view. Look at this image: https://www.dmcinfo.com/Portals/0/Blog%20Pictures/SharePoint2013_02.png . The image displays the All Documents view, and also other 2 views which you do not have. If you click the Ellipsis (3 dots) button, then click "Modify View", you can follow the steps I posted above.